# What's the behavior the browser encoding URL?

Tags: html, http, browser, encoding

I'm doing a test, how the Firefox encoding character.

But the fact confused me.

HTML code:

```
<html lang="zh_CN">
<head>
<title>some Chinese character</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<img src="http://localhost/xxx" />
</body>
```

The xxx is some Chinese characters. These character must be encode into format like %xx to transport by HTTP.

First, I encoding the **source file** in UTF-8. use firefox to open the html file. The img label will send a request, "xxx" character were encoded by UTF8.

- (*encode HTML source file by UTF8, charset=utf8*, the browser encode URL by UTF)

I changed the meta into
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gbk">`
but nothing changed.

- (*encode HTML source file by UTF8, charset=gbk*, the browser encode URL by UTF)

Second, I save the **source file in ANSI**, maybe GBK or GB2312.

when the charset=gbk, still encoding the character by UTF8.

- (*encode HTML source file by GBK, charset=gbk*, the browser encode URL by UTF)

BUT, when the charset=utf8, the characters were encoding by GBK. By the way, other Chinese character can't display in right way, e.g. the String in title.

- (*encode HTML source file by GBK, charset=utf8*, the browser encode URL by GBK)

How to control the browser's encoding behavior?

Comment: I did this test because I encounter a problem when force the browser's URL encoding to utf8, I changed the charset but nothing happened. so I think is there any other thing I don't understand about the browser encoding URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTF-8 is [the standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) for URL encoding. If you encode your source file physically in GBK, but use `utf-8` in the content-type, you are just lying to the browser and will get inconsistent or non-working results.

> When a new URI scheme defines a component that represents textual data
> consisting of characters from the Universal Character Set [UCS], the
> data should first be encoded as octets according to the UTF-8
> character encoding [STD63]; then only those octets that do not
> correspond to characters in the unreserved set should be percent-
> encoded.  For example, the character A would be represented as "A",
> the character LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH GRAVE would be represented
> as "%C3%80", and the character KATAKANA LETTER A would be represented
> as "%E3%82%A2

Comment: I changed my approach, directly print the encoded URL to webpage. Thanks your answer.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking RFC 3986 only uses "should" when talking about using UTF-8, so the standard does allow exceptions. However, in practice at least all modern browsers will encode URLs as UTF-8.